# How to display a text when button click when all the * input are not fill and when fill the * go hide?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like some help where there a text where i would like to display if the button is press and this text appear * is mandatory if the input field are not fill up with those there are * how can i do this ?

This is my snippet where i have all the form created now i would want that this * is mandatory when the add button is press when the input is not fill up how can i do that  ?

```js
$('#submitbutton').click(function() {
  var passwordInput = $('#passwords')
  //Empty password validation
  if (passwordInput.val() == '') {
    $('.password-notmeet').show();
    $('#mandatoryField').show();
    // $('.password-empty').show();
    return;
  } else {
    $('#mandatoryField').hide();

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>

  <label id="mandatoryField" class="hiddenfield">* is mandatory</label>

  <div class="form-group row nameform">
    <label for="validationName" class="col-form-label nameadduser">*Name:</label>
    <div class="col-6">
      <input name="validationName" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationName" placeholder="Name" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Enter a Name!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationEmail" class="col-form-label emailadduser">*Email:</label>
    <div class="col-6">
      <input name="validationEmail" type="email" class="form-control emails" id="validationEmail" placeholder="example1@gmail.com" pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"
        required>
      <div style="margin-left: 3px;" class="invalid-feedback">
        Enter a correct Email format!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationUserName" class="col-form-label usernameadduser">*Username:</label>
    <div class="col-6 ">
      <input name="validationUserName" type="text" class="form-control " id="validationUserName" placeholder="Username" pattern="^(?=.{4,}$)(?:[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:[a-zA-Z\d])*)+$" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Username must meet the following requirements:

        <b>At least four letter</b>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationpassword" class="col-form-label passwordadduser">*Password:</label>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex">
      <input name="validationpassword" onChange="onChange()" type="password" class="form-control pass" id="passwords" placeholder="Password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{7,}$" required>
      <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="togglePassword"></i>
      <!-- <div style="margin-left: 15px;" class="invalid-tooltip password-empty" >
                                    Enter a password!
                                </div> -->
      <div id="passwordvalidator" class="invalid-tooltip password-notmeet">
        Password must meet the following requirements:
        <br><br>
        <label class="color-text"> At least one capital letter</label>
        <br>
        <label class="color-text"> At least one special character</label>
        <br>
        <label class="color-text"> At least one number</label>
        <br>
        <label class="color-text"> Be at least 7 letter</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationconfirmpassword" class="col-form-label passwordadduser">*Re-enter<br>&#10;Password:</label>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex">
      <input name="validationconfirmpassword" onChange="onChange()" type="password" class="form-control confirmpass" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
      <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="toggleconfirmPassword"></i>
      <div style="margin-left: 20px;" class="invalid-tooltip">
        Password do not match or value is null!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="passwordconfirm"></div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationRole" class="col-form-label role">*Role:</label>
    <div class="col-3 ">
      <select class="select-user-role custom-select-sm col-11" id="select-user-role" required>
        <option class="selectrole" selected disabled value="">Select ....</option>
      </select>
      <div style="margin-left: 10px;" class="invalid-feedback">
        Enter a valid user role!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn-primary submitbutton">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some modifications to the HTML to try to make it valid - is this what you were trying to do more or less?

When the `Add` button is clicked the form is initially prevented from the default `submit` behaviour so that ALL input elements might be checked to see if the value is empty. If it is empty a clone of the template contents is made ( with the `* is mandatory` text ) and appended to the parent node. As I am unfamiliar with jQuery the following is all done with vanilla Javascript but no doubt there are some slick jQuery methods that could be used to replace portions of this?!

```js
document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let errors=[];
  
  let col=document.querySelectorAll('input,textarea');
      col.forEach(n=>{
        
        // remove any existing error(mandatory) messages
        let span=n.parentNode.querySelector('span.mandatory');
        if( span!==null ){
          n.parentNode.removeChild(span)
        }
        
        // if the value is empty, add the error (mandatory) message
        if( n.value=='' ){
            let tmpl=document.querySelector('template').content.cloneNode(true);
                tmpl.querySelector('i').textContent=n.name;
            n.parentNode.appendChild( tmpl );
            errors.push(n.name);
          }
      });
      
  if( errors.length==0 ){
    alert('OK - submit the form');
  }
});




const onChange=(e)=>{
  let css={
    err:'invalid',
    ok:'valid'
  };
  
  let col=document.querySelectorAll('.pwdcheck');
      col.forEach(n=>{
        n.classList.remove(css.err,css.ok);
        
        if( col[0].value!=col[1].value )n.classList.add(css.err);
        else n.classList.add(css.ok);
      });
      
};
```

```css
span.mandatory{
  color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0.25rem;
  margin:0,5rem 0;
  border:1px solid red;
  background:pink
}
span.mandatory > i{
  color:white;
}
.invalid-feedback{
  opacity:0;
}
.visible{
  opacity:1;
}
label.col-form-label:before{
  content:'*';
  color:red;
}
.invalid{
  background:pink;
  color:white;
}
.valid{
  background:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<form class='needs-validation' novalidate>

  <div class='form-group row nameform'>
    <label for='validationName' class='col-form-label nameadduser'>Name:</label>
    <div class='col-6'>
      <input 
        name='validationName' 
        type='text'
        class='form-control'
        id='validationName'
        placeholder='Name'
        required />
        
      <div class='invalid-feedback'>
        Enter a Name!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='form-group row'>
    <label for='validationEmail' class='col-form-label emailadduser'>Email:</label>
    <div class='col-6'>
      <input 
        name='validationEmail' 
        type='email' 
        class='form-control emails'
        id='validationEmail' 
        placeholder='example1@gmail.com' 
        pattern='^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$'
        required />
        
      <div style='margin-left: 3px;' class='invalid-feedback'>
        Enter a correct Email format!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class='form-group row'>
    <label for='validationUserName' class='col-form-label usernameadduser'>Username:</label>
    <div class='col-6 '>
      <input 
        name='validationUserName' 
        type='text'
        class='form-control'
        id='validationUserName' 
        placeholder='Username' 
        pattern='^(?=.{4,}$)(?:[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:[a-zA-Z\d])*)+$' 
        required />
        
      <div class='invalid-feedback'>
        Username must meet the following requirements:
        <b>At least four letter</b>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>



  <div class='form-group row'>
    <label for='passwords' class='col-form-label passwordadduser'>Password:</label>
    <div class='col-6 d-flex'>
      <input 
        name='validationpassword'
        onChange='onChange(event)'
        type='password'
        class='form-control pass pwdcheck'
        id='passwords'
        placeholder='Password'
        pattern='^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{7,}$'
        required />
        
      <i class='bi bi-eye-slash' id='togglePassword'></i>

      <div id='passwordvalidator' class='invalid-tooltip password-notmeet'>
        Password must meet the following requirements:
        <div class='color-text'> At least one capital letter</div>
        <div class='color-text'> At least one special character</div>
        <div class='color-text'> At least one number</div>
        <div class='color-text'> Be at least 7 letter</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='form-group row'>
    <label for='confirm_password' class='col-form-label passwordadduser'>Re-enter<br>&#10;Password:</label>
    <div class='col-6 d-flex'>
      <input 
        name='validationconfirmpassword'
        onChange='onChange(event)'
        type='password'
        class='form-control confirmpass pwdcheck'
        id='confirm_password'
        placeholder='Confirm Password'
        required />
        
      <i class='bi bi-eye-slash' id='toggleconfirmPassword'></i>
      <div style='margin-left: 20px;' class='invalid-tooltip'>
        Password do not match or value is null!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id='passwordconfirm'></div>

  <div class='form-group row'>
    <label for='select-user-role' class='col-form-label role'>Role:</label>
    <div class='col-3'>
    
      <select class='select-user-role custom-select-sm col-11' id='select-user-role' required>
        <option value='' class='selectrole' selected disabled hidden>Select ....
      </select>
      
      <div style='margin-left: 10px;' class='invalid-feedback'>
        Enter a valid user role!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type='submit' class='btn-primary submitbutton'>Add</button>
</form>



<template>
  <span class='mandatory'>* <i></i> is mandatory</span>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks through but after a white i think for now is unneccessary 
yeap maybe there a better way to do it